# Gradle phantom dependency showing up in Gradle cache

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

I am trying to make changes to allow a repo of ours to pass a whitesource scan.  The scan is showing several dependencies which it shows as coming from the Gradle package cache but when running the Gradle dependency graph for each module the a lot of these dependencies do not show up as either direct or transient dependencies.  If they are not showing up in the dependency graph then what am I missing?  How are these dependencies being pulled in to show up in the package cache?

Comment: I have witnessed the same thing...were you able to get anywhere on this?